# How to replace a "&" in received XML

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xml

I am receiving a list of inventory from a web service and so far one item has a "&" in it which messes up my parser. So far I have tried:

```
street = [street stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: What exactly happened when you did the street = [street stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"]; ?

Comment: do you have access to edit the format of this xml file ?

Comment: @James- It didn't change it but I might have it in the wrong spot.

Comment: @Louie- If I can't fix it this way yes I have access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML file, replace the `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: do I just use what I have posted above?

Comment: I don't think you should have to use that code that you posted above.  Just make the change I recommended in the XML file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll try

```
street = [street stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```